# Cannot read property of '__dartClass__' of undefined even though i set to a new instance

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I was walking through my code, and started getting errors in my code saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__dartClass__' of undefined
```

and when I looked into it more, I noticed that model is undefined, so my javascript mind just says: *Oh this is a undefined has no property error*.  I took a step back to the parent, put in a print statement and see the model being set:

```
set("model", new SystemModel()..id=4);
```

and in the mark up, i pass it in correctly:

```
<my-component model="{{model}}" ..></my-component>
```

but it still doesnt understand it.

I then started to dissect it more, trying to see what happens if i assign it to something else first, such as:

```
var x = new SystemModel()..id=4;
print("x => $x");
set("model", x);
```

When I did this, I noticed that x was reporting it was an instance of SystemModel, but even then so, when referencing it in the subcomponent, it will kick up the above error.

I am currently using Dartium, but it seems that the property error was in the InteropBehavior._propertyChanged code.  This confuses me, since I didnt think interop would be a thing since I am running it all within dart.

Part of me is thinking that even though this is recognized, some sort of error elsewhere might be preventing it from being passed around correctly.  I havent noticed any errors which are making this jump out at me.

Here is the full print out of the error: [image]

Comment: How does the `Model` and `SystemModel` class look like?

Comment: `SystemModel model;` model is a variable signature to an instance of *SystemModel*

Comment: Please add the source of the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is most probably related to a change in `polymer` that started notifing null properties from a certain version on and the "official" `dart-polymer` not being updated after that.

Try using the latest realeases from https://www.dart-polymer.com/polymer1/ and see if this is still happening.